# Using regex to check if start of a string matches a pattern

Tags: java, regex

I'm reading lines in from a .txt file, and I need to check if each line is 'valid'.

A valid line starts with a number between -2 and 2 inclusive, and is then followed by a single whitespace, and then potentially text.

- "-1 this is valid."
- "0 so is this"
- "-2 and this"
- "2 and this"
- "-1this isn't."
- "-23 nor this"

I want to use regex for this, but am having trouble getting it working. I am quite unfamiliar with regex. Here's my code:

```
public static List<Sentence> readFile(String filename) {
        List<Sentence> sentences = new LinkedList<>();

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("-[0-2] abc");
        Matcher matcher;
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename))) {

            while (br.ready()){
                matcher = pattern.matcher(br.readLine());
                if (matcher.matches()){
                    System.out.print("matches ");
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return sentences;

    }
```

This isn't working (no suprise). Could someone help me out getting the correct regex expression?

Comment: `"-0 is this valid?"`

Comment: No, just 0. Sorry should have included that.

Comment: Thanks.  Also, what characters can the text (at the end) contain?

Comment: replace `abc` by `\\w*`

Comment: The characters after the whitespace can be anything or nothing at all

Comment: Don’t use `ready()` to check for the end of stream.  [It only tells you whether the next read will block,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#ready%28%29) not whether more data exists.  The correct way to look for the end of the data is to check whether `br.readLine()` returns null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be looking for a regex similar to the following:

```
^(0|-?[1-2]) .*
```

The `^` symbol matches the beginning of a line, the `(0|...)` matches `0` or the following expression, the `-?` matches 0 or 1 occurrence of `-`, `[1-2]` matches 1, or 2,  matches a whitespace, and `.*` matches 0 or more of anything but a newline.

Comment: Would the down voter care to explain what is wrong- I'll be more than happy to fix it.

Comment: This is working well thanks (I didn't downvote) -> Thanks for the explanation as well.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not getting your question wrong, you will need something like this as your pattern:

-?[0-2]\s[\w\d\s]*

Try RegExr, it is a very good web based tool for figuring out regex patterns.

Comment: This will also match `-0 `

Comment: Oh right, missed that, thanks Dillon for correcting.

Answer (score 0):

if test strings are separated line by line, then you can validate test strings line by line by

```
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    match = Regex.Match(line, @"^(-?[1-2]\s.*|0\s.*)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    if (match.Success)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(match.Groups[1].Value);
    }
}
```

It validate the test string, and capture the valid string.

As mentioned it works only if the test strings are separated by line.

To modify the regular expression to cater a full string separated by "\n"

It should be

```
string regExp = @"(-?[1-2]\s.+[\n]{1}|(?<!-)0\s.+[\n]{1})";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(longstr, regExp, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
foreach(Match match in matches)
{
    if (match.Success)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(match.Groups[1].Value);
    }
}
```

The concern about full string is, you can no longer apply `^` or `&` in the expression.

Negative match will be occurred and capture the substring "`0 is not valid`" from "`-0 is not valid`" if `^` is removed from the expression

Thus `(?<!-)` is required to it to ignore `-` as the first char when the following char is `0`